# SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to create a string sampler using a rdd of string as a dictionnary and the class [RandomDataGenerator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/random/RandomDataGenerator.scala#L31) from org.apache.spark.mllib.random package.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomDataGenerator
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.util.Random

class StringSampler(var dic: RDD[String], var seed: Long = System.nanoTime) extends RandomDataGenerator[String] {
    require(dic != null, "Dictionary cannot be null")
    require(!dic.isEmpty, "Dictionary must contains lines (words)")
    Random.setSeed(seed)

    var fraction: Long = 1 / dic.count()

    //return a random line from dictionary
    override def nextValue(): String = dic.sample(withReplacement = true, fraction).take(1)(0)

    override def setSeed(newSeed: Long): Unit = Random.setSeed(newSeed)

    override def copy(): StringSampler = new StringSampler(dic)

    def setDictionary(newDic: RDD[String]): Unit = {
        require(newDic != null, "Dictionary cannot be null")
        require(!newDic.isEmpty, "Dictionary must contains lines (words)")
        dic = newDic
        fraction = 1 / dic.count()
    }
}
```

---

```
val dictionaryName: String
val dictionaries: Broadcast[Map[String, RDD[String]]]
val dictionary: RDD[String] = dictionaries.value(dictionaryName) // dictionary.cache()
val sampler = new StringSampler(dictionary)
RandomRDDs.randomRDD(context, sampler, size, numPartitions)
```

But I encounter a SparkException saying that the dictionary is lacking of a SparkContext when I try to generate a random RDD of strings. It seems that spark is loosing context of the dictionary rdd when copying it to cluster nodes and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to cache the dictionary before passing it to the StringSampler, but it didn't change anything...
I was thinking about linking it back to the original SparkContext, but I don't even know if it's possible. Anyone have an idea ?

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here:

```
val dictionaries: Broadcast[Map[String, RDD[String]]]
val dictionary: RDD[String] = dictionaries.value(dictionaryName)
```

You should not be broadcasting anything containing an RDD. RDDs are already parallelized and spread throughout the cluster. The error comes from trying to serialize and deserialize an RDD, which loses its context and is pointless anyway.

Just do this:

```
val dictionaries: Map[String, RDD[String]]
val dictionary: RDD[String] = dictionaries(dictionaryName)
```

Comment: So what is the best option to distribute my dictionaries on a cluster ?

Map[String, RDD[String]], Broadcast[Map[String, Array[String]]] or something else ?

Comment: If you have a small number of dictionaries (say, a few hundred or less), `Map[String, RDD[String]]` is fine. The map keys and some overhead for references to the dictionaries will be in the driver, but the contents of the dictionaries will be distributed around the cluster.

If you have more dictionaries than that, maybe a `RDD[(String, String)]` where each tuple is a (dictionary name, dictionary entry) pair.

Comment: Ok thanks, but sadly I still have the same issue using a `Map[String, RDD[String]]`.
I don't understand why is spark loosing RDDs context. What could be the causes ?
NB: Im passing dictionaries in a scala map function.